# How do I combine two arrays based on the index of their elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to take an array and add its elements to an array of arrays, based on their index.  So if I'm starting with an array

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

and I want to combine that with the array

```
[4, 5, 6]
```

I can get the outcome

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

using this function

```
arr_of_arrays = arr_of_arrays.empty? ? arr : arr_of_arrays.zip(arr).map(&:flatten)
```

However, this breaks down if I try and add an element with more elements than the original.  So if I try and add

```
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

to the original array, right now I'm getting

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

but what I want is

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7]]
```

How do I adjust my above function to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> If the size of any argument is less than the size of the initial array, nil values are supplied.

So you do not need to worry about the case where the second array is shorter.

If the first array is shorter, pad it out with `nil` to the length of the second array.

You can use `compact` to remove the superfluous `nil`s afterwards.

## Case 1: `a` is longer

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8]

a[b.count-1] ||= nil
a.zip(b).map(&:flatten).map(&:compact)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4], [5]]
```

## Case 2: `b` is longer

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

a[b.count-1] ||= nil
a.zip(b).map(&:flatten).map(&:compact)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7], [8]]
```

## Variation with `nil` included

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8]

a[b.count-1] ||= nil
b[a.count-1] ||= nil
a.zip(b).map(&:flatten)     # [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, nil], [5, nil]]
```

... and ...

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

a[b.count-1] ||= nil
b[a.count-1] ||= nil
a.zip(b).map(&:flatten)     # [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [nil, 7], [nil, 8]]
```

## Notes

- If `a` or `b` must not be modified, insert a `.clone` somewhere to clone them beforehand.
- The `.flatten` was taken from the OP's example; it flattens any arrays that take the role of the integers in the example. Keep or leave off as needed.

Comment: If I wanted a "nil" element to appear in the case where one of the arrays is longer, how would I do taht?  So, for example, your case 2 woudl result in [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7, nil], [8, nil]] .  I realize this is a slightly different question so if you want me to do a different post I can do taht.  Thanks

Comment: 1. `a` is mutated in case 2. The OP did not say if that was permitted (in which case we should assume it's a no-no), but even if that's OK, `a` is not mutated in case 1. That inconsistency is a potential problem. 2. `map(&:flatten)` has no effect if, as in the example, the elements of the arrays are not themselves arrays. If, however, they are arrays we might have `a = [[[1,2],3],4]; b = [5,6]; c = a.zip(b) #=> [[[[1, 2], 3], 5], [4, 6]], which is what we would expect, but `c.map(&:flatten) #=> [[1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 6]]`, which is not part of the specification.

Comment: Thanks, @CarySwoveland, added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a "safe" transpose. It's called safe because the usual [`tranpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) raises an error when sub-arrays don't have the same length :

```
def safe_transpose(*arrays)
  l = arrays.map(&:length).max
  arrays.map{|e| e.values_at(0...l)}.transpose.map(&:compact)
end

p safe_transpose([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7])
#=> [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4]]

p safe_transpose([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
#=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

If you want to keep the padded nils, you can use :

```
def safe_transpose(*arrays)
  l = arrays.map(&:length).max
  arrays.map{|e| e.values_at(0...l)}.transpose
end

p safe_transpose([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7])
#=> [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, nil]]

p safe_transpose([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
#=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

The original arrays aren't modified.

Answer (score 0):

I would do...

```
a << nil while a.length < b.length
a.zip(b).map(&:compact)
```

This will change your `a` array, though, so you may want to do the operation on a `dup` of a.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
arr_of_arrays = []
```

i suppose you can easily check that b.size > a.size is true, so

```
b.each_with_index{|elem, index| a[index].nil? ? arr_of_arrays << [elem] : arr_of_arrays << [a[index],elem]}
```

returns the expected array of arrays :

```
=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]

def combine_two_arrays(arr1, arr2)
  new_arr = (arr1.size > arr2.size) ? arr1.zip(arr2) :  arr2.zip(arr1)
  new_arr.map { |arr| arr.compact.sort }
end 

combine_two_arrays(arr1, arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7]

Array.new([a.size, b.size].max) { |i| [a[i],b[i]].compact }
  #=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7]]
```

This assumes none of the elements of `a` or `b` equal `nil`.

If you want `nil`s included, just remove `.compact`:

```
Array.new([a.size, b.size].max) { |i| [a[i],b[i]] }
  #=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [nil, 7]]
```

In this case `a` and `b` are permitted to have `nil` values.